# Cannot seem to identify error in JNC statement in 8085 assembly

Tags: assembly, embedded, simulator, opcode, 8085

I wrote a fairly frugal program to compare 2 numbers , the first JNC statement works fine, the second throws an error, I am using [gnusim8085](https://github.com/GNUSim8085/GNUSim8085) . Here is my code

```
MVI B,03H
MVI C,02H
MOV A,B
CMP C
JNC NO_ZERO_1
MOV H,C
NO_ZERO_1: MOV A,C
CMP B
JNC FINAL
MOV H,B
FINAL:HLT
```

The error being shown is Invalid opcode or pseudo op.
Basically I am checking for carry flag only, and moving the greater number to register H

Comment: Just as a guess, maybe you need a space between `FINAL:` and `HLT`?

Comment: Yikes you are right, should have tried it, much thanks

Comment: @RasenRhino Please awrite an answer explaining the error and the solution and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I would have actually, but it shows the question closed because of typos. The answer is to simply space between FINAL: and HLT. That solves the error of "invalid opcode"